# Creating a div or SVG with a certain form

Tags: svg, shapes

i'm having issues creating a div that mimics the following image:

I need a div with the following form so i can put images inside of them, so if anyone has enough knowledge and can provide support i would really appreciate it.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69uXj.png)

Comment: Would be glad to help andit would be helpful to see what you have so far. Do you have some code examples?

Comment: Download an SVG editor such as Inkscape and draw the shape you want in it.